# How to change table schema when importing data with Hadoop Sqoop to Hive?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

When importing data from MySQL to Hadoop Hive I need to add additional 'timestamp' field to a new table that Hive creates.

```
Input: MySQL table fields : Name, e-nmail, address
Output: Hive table fileds : Name, e-nmail, address, timestamp
```

Questions:

1. How to request Sqoop to add a 'timestamp' field to new table that it
   creates to store imported data in Hive?
2. How to modify schema (add /
       delete fields) of the existing table in Hive?

Comment: ALTER TABLE table_name ADD|REPLACE COLUMNS (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)

Comment: Thanks! This answers my second question, I assume: How to modify schema (add / delete fields) of the existing table in Hive? What about 1) question?

Comment: What timestamp are you expecting? Time of sqoop import or time of data inserted to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the data that you are selecting from the RDBMS by using the --query parameter in Sqoop. Your command might look something like this:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://host:port/db \
--query 'SELECT name, email, address, NOW() AS timestamp FROM table WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--split-by name \
--hive-import \
--hive-table table \
--target-dir location
```

Comment: @CarterShanklin Thanks Jeremy for the useful info! As another scenario my input may consist of two parts:  1) MySQL table 2) a separate log with timestamps for records in the above table. So in this case I get record timestamps from another source and still need to add them to resulting records in Hive. Not sure if this can be done on the fly with Sqoop ...

Comment: No, you would need to do that as a following step. Sqoop just deals with getting data between relational databases and Hadoop.